# How to reach a Context API method inside of a helper function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I created a file which would contain helper functions for querying the database. My problem is that I have to get my access token through the Context API but I can't call the useContext hook outside of a functional component. I could place the functions inside one, but I don't need the component, it would be unused. What is the best practice here?

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { AuthContext } from "../../contexts/auth-context.js";
import { mongoQuery } from "../xhr/QueryMongo";

const { getAccessToken } = useContext(AuthContext);
export async function fetchUserData(userId) {
  const sRealmApp = "...";
  const CancelTokenLogin = axios.CancelToken;
  const sourceLogin = CancelTokenLogin.source();
  let token = await getAccessToken("users");

  const userQuery = `query {user (query:{_id:"${userId}"}) {name, role, residence }}`;
  let queryResult = await mongoQuery(token, sRealmApp, userQuery, sourceLogin);
  if (queryResult.data.data !== null && queryResult.data.data.user !== null) {
    return queryResult.data.data.user;
  } else return false; 
   
 //other similar helper functions....
}
```

(Why I'm creating a new file: I'm refactoring my code because I have a file which has 400 lines of code, but it's not a big project. So I decided to extract code which connects to the database because it's not directly linked to the component.)

Comment: Where do you use `AuthContext.Provider` where you pass the actual context? You could export the context and import it here. Otherwise if these helper functions are used within your components, you could turn `fetchUserData` in a `useUserData` hook.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs I return `AuthContext.Provider` inside of  `AuthProvider` component and then export `{AuthProvider, AuthContext}` where  `AuthContext = React.createContext()`. Also, if I turn that function into a hook, I'm going to need 3-4 more hooks for other similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide the context as a parameter for your helper function.

helperFunction.js

```
fetchUserData(userId, token) {
   ... rest of code
}
```

Component.js
Then get the token from your component using useContext

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import context from 'location of context';
import fetchUserData from 'location of helper function';

const Component = () => {
   const userId = 123; // Not sure where you are getting this, but for example.
   const {getToken} = useContext(context);

   useEffect(() => {
      fetchUserData(userId, getToken());
   }, []);
   return (JSX)
};
```

Although, I don't think this is the best approach. I've done this before and it makes testing a nightmare. Creating a customHook would be a better approach imo.

Comment: thanks, I thought of passing it as a parameter, but it didn't seem ok because I would only need it for the helper functions and it isn't directly linked to the component. Would I need a customHook for each of the helper functions and could you explain where would I define it, inside a new component?